# Alert not popping up for string ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, alert

I'm stuck again with alertboxes!

This works like a charm:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + "Hello"+ "');</script>");
```

*result* is a string. I need to display that. This is where my problem comes in. This doesn't popup:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + result + "');</script>");
```

I am passing *result* across many layers. Also I have used this format in all pages. Don't want a message box. Or a modal popupwindow. I want this. 
I checked online and according to the syntax, it is supposed to work! Please help!

Comment: in what context is the `Response.Write`?

Comment: @NiranjanThangaiya It doesn't display anything. I inserted a breakpoint. Doesnt work for `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello");` or `            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result);`

Comment: @divinediu try my ans, it may be help

Comment: little help from @Guffa try this Response.Write("<script> alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result) + "'); </script>"); it will convert all kind of text, no need to replace anything in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put any value in a Javascript string literal, you need to escape apostrophes (as they are used as the delimiter for the string) and backslashes:

```
Response.Write(
  "<script>" +
  "alert('" + result.Replace("'", "\\'").Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "');" +
  "</script>"
);
```

Comment: Thankyou SO MUCH Found out what my issue was. An exception was thrown and it had apostrophes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"+result+"')</script>")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script> alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result) + "'); </script>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String message = String.format({0}{1}{2},
  "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('",
  result,
  "')</script>");

Response.Write(message);
```